# Unable to run.Is it in your path?(Atom,Ubuntu)

Tags: python, path, atom-editor

Just started learning,so pretty newbie issue.
I'm trying to run a simple hello world script on atom but i get this
`Did you start Atom from the command line?`
atom .
Is it in your PATH?

PATH:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`
I started it from the terminal but it doesn't resolves the issue.Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run Atom if you look under the Atom menu there is a selection 'install shell commands'. When you click this it will enable you to run Atom from the command line by typing atom. Once you do this type 'which atom' and if you get a response, then atom is in your path.